# test API with phpunit laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, phpunit

so I have created a test class in /test directory
in a testExample function, I have store input and output JSON string into a variable.

converted input and output strings to array by using
json_decode(inputstring, true); json_decode(outputstring, true);

I have used following to test this API

```
$this->json('POST', 'api/v1/tagging', $input, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])
            ->seeJson([
                'conversion_specs' => ["post_engagement"],
            ]);
```

Where conversion_specs: `["post_engagement"]` is one of the section of output json

how could I assert it and it is printing too much data after hitting 
`./vendor/bin/phpunit` command

I think it's going wrong, can anyone help me to check an API with expected value.

Comment: using postman, you can test your api. https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: yes  @Abdullah Al Shakib I have tested on postman and working on to write test case using phpunit in laravel 5.2
can you please tell me hot test an API I have input and output JSON string (which I have taken from postman) just need test it using phpunit

Comment: Can you post what you have tried in phpunit so far?

Comment: Maybe I'm not following what you're asking but it sounds like you just want to compare your expected json with whatever is returned,  `$this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);`

Comment: I am hitting API, which gives me particular JSON response, I wanna test it with phpunit, so I got $this->json() method in laravel 5.2 doc which hits post request is it correct .... if yes then please tell me how can I use seeJson()